# Stylesheets not linking

Tags: php, css, href, stylesheet

I am building up a website with PHP and HTML
Stylesheets not linking.
Directory :
 public > staff > index.php
    public > stylesheets > staff.css

What I’ve tried :
    1. Path 1 :   href="public/stylesheets/staff.css" />
    2. Path 2 :   href=“../stylesheets/staff.css" />
    3. URL : http://localhost/php/globe_bank%20/public/staff/staff.css ( not showing ) with another browers
    4. Current directory : href="./stylesheets/staff.css" />
    5. Nest stylesheets file in the staff directory and href="stylesheets/staff.css" />

This is code

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>GBI</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="../stylesheets/staff.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
     <header>
     </header>


  <navigation>
    <ui>
      <li><a href="index.php">Menu</a></li>
    </ui>
 </navigation>

  <footer>
      &copy; <?php echo date('Y'); ?> Globe Bank
  </footer>
```

Comment: if you use a single slash / in-front of your path it will bring the file traversing to the public_html directory.  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="/stylesheets/staff.css" />

Comment: did you ckeck uppercase name maybe ?

Comment: if you are using a relative path, the stylesheet needs to be relative to the url serving the page (not the php file) otherwise do as will says and use an absolute path

Comment: In your top section you have the directories marked as `Staff` and `Stylesheets` but your code uses lower case in the paths `staff` & `stylesheets`. Verify the case of all files and directories. Also, consider removing the `space character` at the end of `globe_bank`

Comment: My bad. The directories are lowercase : stylesheets & staff

Comment: It's supposed to traverse to the public directory and then go to stylesheets folder. Bc the stylesheets folder is nested in public directory. @Will

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html> 
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>GBI</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="../public/stylesheets/staff.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
     <header>
     </header> 
  <navigation>
    <ui>
      <li><a href="index.php">Menu</a></li>
    </ui>
 </navigation>

  <footer>
      &copy; <?php echo date('Y'); ?> Globe Bank
  </footer>`enter code here`
```

Comment: I've tired this. But the css is not linking, but showing the html without style applied